# Border becomes wider when position it with translate

Tags: html, css

I want to have a vertical line which always stays in the middle of div container, no matter of screen size, and I also want it to be 1px thin. But when I add transform: `translate(-50%, -50%);` , I don't know why, but my border becomes fatter then I expected. This is my HTML/CSS code.

```css
.cases-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    width: 480px;
    height: 110px;
    position: relative;
}
.item-border {
    border-left: 1px solid #ff5a00;
    height: 95px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```html
<div class="cases-container">
      
  <div class="item-border"></div>
    
</div>
```

So, what is the issue here ?

Comment: I seem to see your example just fine, but this might have to do with the fact that there is no middle pixel in a 480px wide div. Try making it 481px wide see if that changes anything. Different browsers have different ways of dealing with this kind of situations, half pixels, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code for your reference:

1. List item

```css
.cases-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    width: 480px;
    height: 110px;
    position: relative;
}
.item-border {
    border-left: 1px solid #ff5a00;
    height: 95px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
```

```html
<div class="cases-container">
      
  <div class="item-border"></div>
    
</div>
```